# в JAR-файле не работают картинки

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gui, jar

Есть небольшое GUI приложение, состоящее из нескольких окошек, в котором используются картинки (работаю в `Intellij Idea`).

Они лежат в отдельной папке в `src/`. Когда собираю JAR, он помещается в папку `out/artifacts`. Запускаю его в этой папке, все работает, а когда копирую JAR-файл на рабочий стол, все работает, но картинки пропадают.

Попробовал использовать:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MainClass.class.getResource("URL"));
```

И пометить папку с картинками как Resources Root, но как-то не помогло.

Может проблему можно как-то через `Project Structure`, `Project Settings` исправить?

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: какой  именно URL вы используете?

Comment: "src/main/resources/" + fileName.png

Comment: а в jar файле есть картинки? по какому пути они расположены?

Comment: Когда из проекта собираю JAR-файл, система кладет собранный JAR в папку projectname/out/artifacts. Когда запускаю JAR из этой папки, картинки работают, когда копирую JAR-файл на рабочий стол - нет. Папка с картинками находится по адресу: projectname/img (URL в предыдущем комментарии из другого проекта, ошибся), пометил её как Resources Root. Картинки подгружаю так (использую в проекте BufferedImage): ImageIO.read(MainClass.class.getResource("img/" + fileName.png));

Comment: @Ant во-первых все пути к ресурсам должны начинаться со `/` (самая расположен ошибка при работе с ресурсами), во вторых надо посмотреть где внутри jar оказались картинки (это можно сделать любым архиватаром), я не уверен как IDEA работает с Resource Root, возможно он оказались в папке img, тогда путь будет `"/img/fileName.pmg"`, либо они могли оказаться в корне архива, тогда путь будет `"/fileName.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропишите в `pom.xml` файле (если у вас `Maven`) путь к ресурсам и обращайтесь к ним через `getResource()`

Comment: У меня был не Maven, просто JAVA-проект. Но создал Mаven-проект, в нем .java файлы лежат в папке src/main/java, а .png файлы - в src/main/resources. POM-файл получился такой

Comment: Извиняюсь, скриншот не знаю как прикрепить. В общем, POM-файл: <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.png</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources> Загружаю .png-файлы: ImageIO.read(Engine.class.getResource("src/main/resources/" + fileName)); Компилятор пишет: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
 at Engine.loadIcon(Engine.java:217)